# Refer to an object initialized Asynchronously with an HTTP service

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I have a class that contains an array of an object called LearningElementDTO , which is being initialized on the ngOnInit() method  Asynchronously with observable .
the problem i have is when i try to refer to this array at the loading of the component , i got the  error :
Cannot read property '0' of undefined

the problem here is that i refer to the object LearningElementDTO[0] befor it was initialized .

```
  private learningElements: LearningElementDTO[];

  constructor(private service: LearningService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();

    // here is where the undefined problem happens 
    console.log(this.learningElements[0].name);
  }
  private loadData(): void {
    this.service.getLearningElements().subscribe(
      (reponse: any) => {
        this.learningElements = reponse;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

is there any workaround to avoid referring to abjects that are initialized in the same way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pipe` for this:

```
private learningElements: LearningElementDTO[];

constructor(private service: LearningService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData().subscribe(reponse => {
      console.log(this.learningElements[0].name);
    });
}

private loadData(): Observable<LearningElementDTO[]>{
    return this.service.getLearningElements().pipe(
      map((reponse: any) => {
        this.learningElements = reponse;
        return response;
      })
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you explain why should i return  an Observable since the function has only the mission of  loading the data into LearningElementDTO[] ?

Comment: @redd77 `this.service.getLearningElements().subscribe()` is an `async` operation, so you were starting it in `ngOnInit` but then weren't waiting for it to complete before trying to `console.log(this.learningElements[0].name);`. In this case, we choose to return an observable so that we can essentially be notified on the completion of this process. The main point is that you weren't waiting for the `async` process previously.

Answer (score 1):

When your `console.log` is executed, the response hasn't come back yet. You need to move this code into your `subscribe` function after you assign the server response to your local variable `this.learningElements`

```
this.service
    .getLearningElements()
    .subscribe(response => {
        this.learningElements = response;
        console.log(this.learningElements[0].name);
    });
```